# serializer.is_valid() = false when posting an object from AngularJS frontend to Django backend

Tags: angularjs, django

I have an AngularJS front-end and a Django backend.

The front-end calls the backend using the following two $http calls:

```
athleticsApp.controller('athletesListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.athletes = [];

    $scope.getAthletes = function(){
        $http
            .get('http://serverip:8666/athletics/athletes/')
            .success(function(result) {
                $scope.athletes = result;
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
            });
    }

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.getAthletes();
    }

    $scope.init();

}]);


athleticsApp.controller('athleteNewController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.athlete = {
        firstName : '',
        lastName : ''
    };

    $scope.postNewAthlete = function(){
        $http
            .post('http://serverip:8666/athletics/athletes/', $scope.athlete)
            .success(function(result) {
                // set url fraction identifier to list athletes
            })
    }
}]);
```

The GET call is a success. The POST call generates the following error:

> 400 (BAD REQUEST)

When I run the Python debugger I can see that `serializer.is_valid()` is false.

```
(Pdb) serializer = AthleteSerializer(data=request.data)

(Pdb) serializer
AthleteSerializer(data={u'lastName': u'Smith', u'firstName': u'John'}):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=30)

(Pdb) serializer.is_valid()
False
```

The Django code looks like this:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from views import Athletes

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^athletes/', Athletes.as_view()),
]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Athlete
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from athletics.serializers import AthleteSerializer

class Athletes(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        all_athletes = Athlete.objects.all()
        serializer = AthleteSerializer(all_athletes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        serializer = AthleteSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            creation_data = serializer.save()
            return Response()


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'athletics/index.html')
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Athlete

class AthleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Athlete
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        )
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysitedjango project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secretkey'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

INTERNAL_IPS = (
    'myip'
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

REQUIRED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Third party apps
    'rest_framework',

)

PROJECT_APPS = (
    # This project
    'athletics',
    'testetics',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = REQUIRED_APPS + PROJECT_APPS

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysitedjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysitedjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Stockholm'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Where do you include the `csrf_token`?

Comment: @Sayse: Nowhere, I haven't figured out how to do that even though I've read about it. I've edited my original post to show my settings as well.

Comment: Thats more than likely the issue, you verify it by adding `@csrf_exempt` to your post method, although you should not keep it there

Comment: @Sayse: I just tried adding that decorator to the django post method. It didn't make any difference. Since the request is accepted by Django, as indcated by the debug code, and not forbidden, I think that the problem might be something else.